# Failed to parse manifest - Virtual manifests must be configured with [workspace]

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, toml

I'm running this in powershell for my Rust project:

`cargo build --target thumbv7em-none-eabihf`

And it produces this error after I try to execute this command:

`error: failed to parse manifest at C:\Users\PC\Downloads\Blizzard\Cargo.toml Caused by: virtual manifests must be configured with [workspace]`

Here is my Cargo.toml file:

```ini
[package]
name = "my-project"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["runner"]
edition = "2021"

[profile.dev]
panic = "abort"

[profile.release]
panic = "abort"
```

If it's needed, here is my rust file:

```
#![no_std]
#![no_main]

use core::panic::PanicInfo;

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn _start() -> ! {
    loop {}
}

#[panic_handler]
fn panic(_info: &PanicInfo) -> ! {
    loop {}
}
```

And my file path looks like this:

```
> Blizzard
  > src
   > main.rs
  > Cargo.toml
```

How can I fix this issue? Any help is appreciated

Comment: I googled and found this [post](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/problems-with-rust-4175654246/),  perhaps it will be helpful?

Comment: @SteveLau will i need to add the bin/lib part from that solution for it to work?

Comment: Honestly I haven't encontered this error before, so I don't know what to do, sorry:(. This is the official doc for [virtual manifest](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/workspaces.html#virtual-manifest). However, according to the statement from this doc, I don't see any problems in your `Cargo.toml`

Comment: What directory are you in when you run `cargo build`?

Comment: I tried duplicating your folder structure and pasting your code, and the project compiled without problem (with cargo v1.59.0 on a Linux host).

Comment: @KevinReid C:\Users\PC\Downloads\Blizzard> cargo build --target thumbv7em-none-eabihf

Comment: I ran into the same thing. All I had to do was delete my Cargo.lock, make sure my Cargo.toml file was saved, and reran "cargo build" and my problem was solved. I didn't want to put this as an answer because not sure if this will work for your situation. Good luck!